# In Aframe, how to point directional light to a certain position instead to an entity?

Tags: aframe

I want my Directional Light to point to [10,5,5]. I don't have any object there. However, in Aframe documentation, target attributed points only to a certain object.

```
<a-light type="directional" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" target="#directionaltarget">
  <a-entity id="directionaltarget" position="0 0 -1"></a-entity>
</a-light>
```

Answer (score 0):

The target doesn't have to be a "physical" object with a mesh. In this case, it's just an empty dummy object which entire purpose is to provide an anchor point where the light should be directed at.

If you want it to be at `10 5 5`, then just change the dummys position:

```
<a-light type="directional" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" target="#directionaltarget">
  <a-entity id="directionaltarget" position="10 5 5"></a-entity>
</a-light>
```

Keep in mind, that here `10 5 5` is in regard to the parents position, because the target is nested.

---

If you don't want to create an entity, you can create the light in `threejs` - but still it [requires a dummy object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/DirectionalLight.target):

```html
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent("left-light", {
      init: function() {
        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff0000, 1.5); // red light
        const target = new THREE.Object3D(); // dummy target
        directionalLight.target = target; // direct the light onto the target
        directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 0) // move light to the center
        target.position.set(1, 0, 0); // move the target to the right
        // add the target and the light
        this.el.sceneEl.object3D.add(target);
        this.el.sceneEl.object3D.add(directionalLight);
      }
    })
  </script>
  <a-scene left-light>
    <a-light></a-light>
    <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#FFFFFF"></a-box>
    <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#FFFFFF"></a-sphere>
    <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFFFFF"></a-cylinder>
  </a-scene>
```